# Service Fabric Stateful OData service

Tags: odata, azure-service-fabric

is it possible/is there an example to build a stateful service that exposes OData endpoint?

The point is to collect data in such a service and then expose the collection via OData endpoint

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can expose any kind of endpoint using whatever protocol or framework you want in a stateful service. I recommend using [OData for Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api).

Here's an example project that uses Web API in a stateful service: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/Services/WordCount/WordCount.Service

Comment: Nice, looking at the code now I have more questions - what happens when there are more instances of this service (with more partitions). The listener builds an address of the PartitionId, ReplicaId, and a random string. How do clients find the right url? Should I put a stateless service in front to route the request to correct partition? How would I go about that?

Comment: Yes, a stateless service is the ingress point for your services and it connects to a partition of your stateful service based on a partition key that you produce from the incoming request. The example I linked to follows this pattern; there is a stateless service project in there (WebService) that does this. Also see here for more background info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/